# how to list all Oracle ASM disks on the server?

Tags: command-line, server, disk, disk-management

I want to list all Oracle ASM disks (Only Oracle ASM Disks) on a server & to do so I want to know what is the best command. (Here by Oracle ASM Disks, I mean (Oracle Automatic Storage Management Disks))

Apologies for bad English! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to list all Oracle ASM disks & only Oracle ASM disks is using below command.

```
blkid | grep asm
```

This command will list all the Oracle ASM disks available on the server. this command will list those Oracle ASM disks as well which are carved out of SAN LUNs.